# Java Compiler error: can't find (SINGLE_CHOICE_MODE);

Tags: android

Here's my code fragment:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActvity;
import android.app.ListView;
import android.app.AbsListView;
import android.app.AdapterView;
....

public class MyDemo extends ListActivity {
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        ListView myLV = (ListView) findViewByID(R.id.ListView1);
        myLV.setChoiceMode(SINGLE_CHOICE_MODE); 
    }
}
```

When I try to compile, javac reports error: can't find symbol 
SINGLE_CHOICE_MODE.  Any ideas?  Am I not importing the correct file?

Comment: Isn't it `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE`?

Comment: Yes, right you are. Don't know I how wrong order I words got the. Never this to me before happened.  You Thank!

Comment: Actually, I tried CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, and I get the same compiler error: cannot find symbol: variable CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE` constant is a member of the `ListView` class. Correct usage:

```
myLV.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Comment: ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to call the correct constant, which is [`CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE).

Comment: Actually, I tried CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, and I get the same compiler error: cannot find symbol: variable CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE